# Iterable< ? extends iface_class >

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Can someone tell me what does it mean by this line?

```
class_A
...
Iterable< ? extends iface_classB> getThings();
```

where iface_classB can be either interface/abstract of classB here.

i got the error when i write something as:

```
class_A myA = new classA()

Iterable< impl_of_iface_classB > anIterator = myA.getThings()
```

I wonder about question mark inside the template. My guess was that it should be anything that derive from `iface_classB` but it seems i was wrong.

Thank you very much for any answer.

Comment: Please show the error. Also make sure you're not confusing Iterator and Iterable. From what you're showing it should work.

Comment: eclipse marked as something wrong at this line. i also don't understand about Iterator...since I am new to Java. My book that I have doesn't cover these new standard of Java. what is the different between Iterable and Iterator class? Can someone put the link to the answer or give me short explaination about them?

Comment: You should stick to naming conventions when asking in public.

Answer (score 4):

The assumption you made is the opposite of what really stands:

```
Iterable<? extends iface_classB> getThings();
```

means that `getThings()` returns an iterable of objects that have **at least** the functionality of `iface_classB`. Hence you cannot assign the result from `getThings()` to any `Iterable< impl_of_iface_classB >` because you are only sure that the objects expose the functionality of a `iface_classB`.

For example, what if the object returned by `getThings()` actually is an `Iterable<impl2_of_iface_classB>`, where `impl2_of_iface_classB` extends `iface_classB`? 
The iterable objects won't have the functionality of `impl_of_iface_classB` objects.

In practice, if `B1` and `B2` are derived from `B`, it is perfectly allowed to have

```
A<? extends B> x; 
A<B1> y;
A<B2> z;

x = y;
x = z;
```

hence `getThings()` cannot be relied upon in terms of what the generic parameter stands for: it can be consumed only as a "plain" `iface_classB`.

More to the point, you would expect to be able to assign to an `Iterable<iface_classB>`, but you cannot (not unless you perform an unchecked cast, that is). This is because the wildcard symbol essentially means "a set of feasible generic parameters". Imagine that you substitute the wildcard with the concrete generic parameter that you use: if the parameters do not match, you get the usual compile-time error due to incompatible types. The compiler, having to account for all cases, does not allow you to do that. Therefore,

```
A<? extends B> x;
A<B> y = x;
```

while effectively safe, is not allowed because `x` may be assigned a parameter different from `B`, yielding different types for the two sides of the assignment. On the contrary,

```
A<B> x;
A<? extends B> y = x;
```

is allowed because the type of `y` represents a **set of alternatives**, and that set includes `A<B>`. As soon as `y` is assigned like above, the concrete valuation of the set is actually chosen.

Answer (score 3):

This is the part of generics and it is related to wildcard character 
Check this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html